# Custom font color for PagerTabStrip in ViewPager for my Android app

Tags: android-viewpager

I need to change the font color for PagerTabStrip in ViewPager for my Android app. This is the xml layout for the same. Is there any way I can do this?

```
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/head"
    android:id="@+id/myfivepanelpager">

        <android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
         android:id="@+id/pgstrip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/strip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/pagerstripht"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />

    </android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>
```

Answer (score 12):

in your code :

```
<android.support.v4.view.PagerTabStrip
         android:id="@+id/pgstrip"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:background="@color/strip"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/pagerstripht"
        android:layout_gravity="top"
        />
```

I think adding android:textColor="#000" will change the text color.

Comment: Not sure why this answer has been down-voted?! Setting the `textColor` attribute does indeed change the color of the text in a `PagerTabStrip`.

Comment: It actually worked!! But I dont know why android hint didnt show up this particular option

Answer (score 11):

If you haven't found out yet, code is below

```
PagerTabStrip pagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
pagerTabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(true);
pagerTabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 10):

Get the child views of the PagerTabStrip and check if it is an instance of a TextView. If it is, set text color:

```
PagerTabStrip mPagerTabStrip = (PagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pgstrip);
for (int i = 0; i < mPagerTabStrip.getChildCount(); ++i) {
    View nextChild = mPagerTabStrip.getChildAt(i);
    if (nextChild instanceof TextView) {
        TextView textViewToConvert = (TextView) nextChild;
        textViewToConvert.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.primary_text_color_dark_gray));
    }
}
```

Comment: I would upvote this if there was a little explanation for the code.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use:

```
pagerTabStrip.setTextColor(int color);
```

[image]